# Display a category for each post (custom post)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display the category for every post I get on the custom post page.
like this: [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKWgw.png) (this picture is from another web site).

This is my function.php:

```
function create_post_type()
{
    register_post_type('oglasi', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Oglasi') ,
            'singular_name' => __('Oglasi')
        ) ,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_type', 'create_category');

function oglasi_kategorije()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Oglasi Kategorije', 'taxonomy general name') ,
        'singular_name' => _x('Kategorije Oglasa', 'taxonomy singular name') ,
        'search_items'      => __('Pretrazi Kategorije') ,
        'all_items'         => __('Sve Kategorije') ,
        'parent_item'       => __('Roditelj Kategorije') ,
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Roditelj Kategorije') ,
        'edit_item'         => __('Uredi Kategoriju') ,
        'update_item'       => __('Azuriraj Kategoriju') ,
        'add_new_item'      => __('Dodaj Novu Kategoriju') ,
        'new_item_name'     => __('Nova Ktegorija') ,
        'menu_name'         => __('Kategorije Oglasa') ,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,

        // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'kategorije')

    );
    register_taxonomy('oglasi_kategorije', 'oglasi', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'oglasi_kategorije', 0);
```

I need to display category on archive-oglasi.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128030/display-a-posts-category-within-the-wordpress-loop

Samo jako, mora proci XD

Comment: Nadam se da hoce!  :D

Comment: Ali ipak mislim da nije to to :D meni treba da kada izbacim post da ispod posta ili bilo gde drugde u tom kontejneru mi izbaci u koju sam ga kategoriju stavio :D

Comment: Probaj ispisati post
echo "<pre>";
     print_r($post)
echo "</pre>";

----------------sa ovim ces dobiti sve o postu ukljucujuci i kategoriju pa je pokupi kao niz, $post[category]---------- ako to ne mogne onda loadaj post po id i onda ga opet ispisi i uzmi kategoriju :D

Comment: Zanimljivo je to sto mi ne prikazuje kategorije sa print_r($post) , ali sve ostalo da?